# Messagebox.show error in htttwebresponse method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have following response code.I got error like An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user codeerror, when call Messagebox.sohw() method to show code : 200.
My Json is like {"meta":{"code":200}}

```
          private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
          {
           HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.EndGetResponse(ar);
uritext.Text = myResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();    
            }
            myResponse.Close();
           var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsondata);
           String codenum = root.meta.code.ToString();
           Messagebox.sohw(codenum);
           }
   public class Meta
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the callback from the `HttpWebRequest` occurs from a non-UI thread.

Here is what you can do to execute `MessageBox.Show` on the UI thread:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(codenum));
```

Comment: how i can use httpWebrequest to avoid this problem ?         protected  override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            String accesstoken = NavigationContext.QueryString["access_token"];
            HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(access_uri + accesstoken);
            myReq.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), myReq);
        }

Comment: Just replace the line where you call MessageBox.Show in the ReadWebRequestCallback method to the code written in my answer.

Comment: how i can pass method like test() in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke();

Comment: Just copy/paste the code line of my anwser! It uses an Anonymous function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx)